# Three.js - DragControls not detecting intersections

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to setup `DragControls` in my Three.js application. Reading documentation online, this seems a rather straight forward process. My code is as follows:

```
let dragObjects = [obj]
const dragControls = new DragControls(dragObjects, camera, renderer.domElement);

dragControls.addEventListener("hoveron", function (event) {
    console.log(event.object)
})

dragControls.addEventListener("hoveroff", function (event) {
    console.log(event.object)
})
```

Normally, this code should allow me to drag the `obj` around and log the `obj` to the console whenever `hoveron` and `hoveroff` events are triggered. However, nothing happens. The object is not draggable and nothing is printed to the console. No error messages are provided.

I’ve copied all the code from the library into my own file to be able to debug in more depth. From this I noticed that no intersections are ever detected by the RayCaster.

Some remarks that might be useful to know:

- I currently only have one object in the array for testing purposes, these are supposed to be multiple in the future
- I add my objects to specific layers. The object I pass in the array is on a layer that is active.
- I have a domElement overlapping my canvas to work with `CSS2DRenderer()`. However, its position is `absolute` and pointer events are `none`.
- I have a `RayCaster()` setup seperatly which I use to make my objects clickable, this works just fine.
- When providing a wrong parameter to the `DragControls()` (e.g. providing a `scene` instead of a `camera`), I do get error messages in my console originating from `DragControls` when mouse events take place. So we can be sure it is at least loaded and doing *something*.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add an animation loop?  If your controls are saved in the variable `controls`, then try `function animate() {requestAnimationFrame( animate ); controls.update(); renderer.render( scene, camera ); }`

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem to be with `Layers`. The `RayCaster` that `DragControls` uses only looks at object on layer 0. Since I used `layers.set()` a lot in my code, layer 0 was automatically removed and objects would never be considered by the raycaster. Solved this by using `layers.enable()` and `layers.disable()` instead.